# Redirecting a page after login in php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am new to php and I googled a simple login form with source code in it. The code was working but it wont redirect me to home page rather it stay still in login page. Here is the code for the authentication that is responsible for redirection if user inputs correct credentials:

```
ob_start();
session_start();
$error='';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    $error="Username or Password is invalid";
}
else{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $cxn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin"); 
    $username=stripslashes($username);
    $password=stripslashes($password);
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $db=mysql_select_db("hrdb",$cxn);
    $query=mysql_query("select * from login where Username='$username' AND 
    Password='$password'",$cxn);

    $rows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['log_user']=$username;
        echo "test";
        header('Location: http://localhost/HRMS/profile.php');
        exit;
    }else{
        $error="Username or password is invalid";
    }
    mysql_close($cxn);
    }
    }
    ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Since you are starting out, great time to tell you not to use any `mysql_` functions. You will want to use `mysqli_` or `PDO` for database connections.

Comment: I tried replacing every mysql to mysqli but i am having many errors like mysqli expects to be resource but string was given so i revert it back to mysql but if you can recode it to fit for mysqli its more than ok.

Comment: If you are practicing, this script is fine, but for real use, this is not a good script.

Comment: echo the`$rows` value. `$rows=mysql_num_rows($query);` should be 1 if the username and password match.

Comment: I tried but nothing was echoed or where should I put it?

Comment: Well if you did `$rows=mysql_num_rows($query); echo $row;` and nothing was there, then that is probably then that you have a problem with your connection, or your query didn't match the username and password.

Comment: Is your table name `login`? And its columns are `Username` and `Password`? Remember that these are CASE SENSITIVE.

Comment: Where you have the `$error="Username or password is invalid";` write `echo $error;` after that. You have no writing to the page regarding that error.

Comment: Yes it echoed 1 because I put only 1 record in it for testing.

Comment: It won't redirect on most servers if you output anything (aka `echo "test";`) before header. Remove that line, see if it goes.

Comment: Also, right after `session_start();` write `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Arrgggh I am getting more and more frustrated as the tutorial said it is 100% percent working.... nothings changed even I delete the echo test.

Comment: This may have been 100% working a few years ago, mind you. This is old script you are testing.

Comment: Remove the `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();`, those are not really necessary for this script. Doesn't add any real advantage here.

Comment: Comment out the `header('Location: http://localhost/HRMS/profile.php');` temporarily, and retest the form. Lets see the result.

Comment: I followed the suggestion of Rasclatt and put after ini_set and error_reporting and commenting out the header and I got this message "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead"

Comment: If you are still getting this error, you need to remove all instances of the `mysql_` in favor of `mysqli_`. The connect may not be `mysqli_` according to the error.

Comment: Yes i changed it from mysql to mysqli but same problem still did not redirect me to profile page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the header() function to send a new HTTP header, but this must be sent to the browser before any HTML or text (so before the  declaration, for example).

You may want to include `die` after the `header` call:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/HRMS/profile.php");
die();
```

Comment: nothings happened stuck in the same page as always.

Comment: @NewbieN you need to do it before you send any output to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use mysqli instead of mysql and
there are minor changes please check it carefully
and test the code it is working fine now.

```
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    $error='';


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
            $error="Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        else{
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password= md5($_POST['password']);

            $cxn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hrdb");
            $username=stripslashes($username);
            $password=stripslashes($password);
            $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$username);;
            $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$password);;

            $query=mysqli_query($cxn,"select * from user_mst_tbl where USER_NAME='".$username."' AND
            PASS_WORD='".$password."'");

            $rows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if($rows==1){
                $_SESSION['log_user']=$username;
                echo "test";
                header('Location: http://localhost/HRMS/profile.php');

            }else{
                $error="Username or password is invalid";
            }
            mysql_close($cxn);
        }
    }
    ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: I tried your code but I am receiving the following errors: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: That's because the example is still using `mysql_ ` in that part

Comment: Should be `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$username);`. Same with the `$password`.

Comment: @Newbie N please try it again i have made changes

Comment: Are getting an error or what you are getting, please specify

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the error:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

because you have installed a later version of XAMPP.

You need to consider using [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) rather than the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` API. You don't need to sanitize each variables before you can use it in your queries, because prepared statement will do it for you.

And if you are going to use `header()` function of PHP, make sure that you don't have any output before you call `header()`.

Check also your `profile.php`, if it has `header()` call too, which redirects the page back to the login page.

```
<?php

/* MAKE SURE THAT THERE ARE NO HTML/OUTPUTS ABOVE THIS CODE */

ob_start();
session_start();
$error = "";

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "admin", "hrdb");

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    $error="Username or Password is invalid";
  }
  else{

    if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Username FROM login WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?")){ /* CHECK AND PREPARE THE QUERY */
      $stmt->bind_param("ss",$_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]); /* BIND THESE VARIABLES TO YOUR PREPARED QUERY; s STANDS FOR STRINGS */
      $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
      $rows = $stmt->num_rows; /* GET NUMBER OF ROWS/RESULTS */
      if($rows == 1){ /* IF FOUND RESULT */
        $stmt->bind_result($username); /* STORE THE RESULT TO THIS VARIABLE */
        $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULT */
        $_SESSION['log_user'] = $username; /* STORE THE RESULT TO THIS SESSION VARIABLE */
        /* header('LOCATION: http://localhost/HRMS/profile.php'); REDIRECT THE PAGE TO profile.php */
        ?>
          <meta http-equiv="refresh" content=".5; URL='profile.php'"/> <!-- REDIRECT TO profile.php IN HALF A SECOND -->
        <?php
      }
      else {
        $error="Username or password is invalid";
      }
      $stmt->close();
    } /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

  } /* END OF ELSE */

} /* END OF ISSET SUBMIT */

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

You should also secure the password being stored in your database. You can use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for it.

Comment: I tried the code yes i didn't get any error but even i inputted the correct username and password it still prompts me that invalid username or password when my username and password is simple as admin and minda consecutively.

Comment: @NewbieN - Your column for your `login` table is `Username` and `Password`, right? I've updated my answer and put `Username` instead of `username` - *CASE SENSITIVE*

Comment: I checked the profile.php but it only have "include('session.php')"

Comment: And what does your `session.php` file contain?

Comment: It only saves the session of the user for future use for other pages like displaying the name of the person currently loggedin.

Comment: Uhh.. Okay. Try my updated query. And get back to me.

Comment: still at the same page.

Comment: Okay, try this. Inside the `if($rows == 1){`, print the `$rows` variable and comment out the `header("LOCATION: profile.php")`. Let me see the result. You can also double check the table name and column names if it matches the data inside your database.

Comment: @NewbieN What is the file name of the code you have posted?

Comment: what filename? I have index.php where you logged in, session.php that records the user profile, profile.php as my home page, logout.php that responds when you logged out

Comment: The code you have posted. In what file did you put it? In your index.php also?

Comment: no separate it was declared inside the index.php as "include('login.php')"

Comment: And where did you include it? At the above of the form? Make sure that you include the `login.php` at the top of the `index.php`, with no outputs

Comment: Dang! I want to see your index.php, session.php and profile.php.

Comment: They rely on the login.php to show up but having this issue stops me from completing my project in time.

Comment: @NewbieN - you can try my updated answer. I removed the `header()` and replaced it with `<meta>`

Comment: @NewbieN - I think the problem is with the other files. There is a file that redirects the page back to the login page.